# Mocking Websocket Server for Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, unit-testing, sockjs

I am using sockJS on the client side for the websockets implementation of my project (the socket server is run by a Java Spring instance). I'm having trouble figuring out how to mock the websockets server for my front end sockets unit testing.

I have some functions that depend on the data being streamed from the server. But I can't figure out how to mock this data such that sock.onmessage is called.

My client is setup in general like this:

**websocket-client.js (sockJS)**

```js
sock = new SockJS('/server/uri');
    
sock.onopen = function() {

};
    
sock.onmessage = function(e) {
  var message = e.data.message;
  displayMessage(message);
};
    
sock.onclose = function() {
  // clean up stuff
};
```

I'm using Karma and Chai for my test runner/assertion library.

Since this is an Angular application, usually I can mock my API services using $httpBackend. But I don't think this is an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to wrap SockJS in a factory/service:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('sockJS', function () {
        return {
            create: function (uri) {
                return new SockJS(uri);
            }
        };
    });
```

Then you can inject sockJS and also mock it.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, sockJS) {
        var sock = sockJS.create('/server/uri');

        sock.onopen = function() {

        };

        sock.onmessage = function(e) {
        // do stuff with e data
        };

        sock.onclose = function() {
        // clean up stuff
        };
    });
```

Comment: This sounds like the proper direction to go. So how would I test the logic going on within sock.onmessage? I need to a way to call the onmessage function, which is usually handled by the sockjs library when the server emits a socket message.

Comment: Can you please add some logic in your question? Is it logic to do with e?

Comment: Yes, so for example I would have a function that parses a string contained in the e object and displays the result to the user. I want to be able to unit test the statements within the onmessage function block. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: I'd assume you would want to unit test what the actual displayMessage method does. Can you please post that?